# Wordpress seems to not accept @keyframes for css music player

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-player

I copied a css music player from Codepen to my wordpress and almost everything works except this particular part of code @keyframe that is supposed to rotate the loading pictogram...

When I copy it to my wordpress it seems like there is a missing right brace but there is not...

The player works on my website, except that the loading pictogram never stop rotating.. So I'm pretty sure it comes from here

Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/molonom/pen/xNJBpq

Can you help me ?

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="audio green-audio-player">
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="play-pause-btn">  
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="24" viewBox="0 0 18 24">
        <path fill="black" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 12L0 24V0" class="play-pause-icon" id="playPause"/>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
      <span class="current-time">0:00</span>
      <div class="slider" data-direction="horizontal">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="pin" id="progress-pin" data-method="rewind"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="total-time">0:00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="volume">
      <div class="volume-btn">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="black" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.667 0v2.747c3.853 1.146 6.666 4.72 6.666 8.946 0 4.227-2.813 7.787-6.666 8.934v2.76C20 22.173 24 17.4 24 11.693 24 5.987 20 1.213 14.667 0zM18 11.693c0-2.36-1.333-4.386-3.333-5.373v10.707c2-.947 3.333-2.987 3.333-5.334zm-18-4v8h5.333L12 22.36V1.027L5.333 7.693H0z" id="speaker"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="volume-controls hidden">
        <div class="slider" data-direction="vertical">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="pin" id="volume-pin" data-method="changeVolume"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <audio crossorigin>
      <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355309/Swing_Jazz_Drum.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.audio.green-audio-player {
  width: 500px;
  height: 56px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-color: white;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .play-pause-btn {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .spinner {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/355309/loading.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: spin 0.4s linear 1;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .slider {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .slider .progress {
  background-color: #47c03c;
  border-radius: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .slider .progress .pin {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: all;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
.audio.green-audio-player .controls {
  font-family: 'Elastik-B', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .controls .slider {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 4px;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .controls .slider .progress {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .controls .slider .progress .pin {
  right: -8px;
  top: -6px;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .controls span {
  cursor: default;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume {
  position: relative;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-btn.open path {
  fill: black;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-controls {
  width: 30px;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  bottom: 52px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-controls.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-controls .slider {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 6px;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-controls .slider .progress {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
}
.audio.green-audio-player .volume .volume-controls .slider .progress .pin {
  left: -5px;
  top: -8px;
}

@keyframes spin {
from {
  transform: rotateZ(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(1turn);}}
```

```
var audioPlayer = document.querySelector('.green-audio-player');
var playPause = audioPlayer.querySelector('#playPause');
var playpauseBtn = audioPlayer.querySelector('.play-pause-btn');
var loading = audioPlayer.querySelector('.loading');
var progress = audioPlayer.querySelector('.progress');
var sliders = audioPlayer.querySelectorAll('.slider');
var volumeBtn = audioPlayer.querySelector('.volume-btn');
var volumeControls = audioPlayer.querySelector('.volume-controls');
var volumeProgress = volumeControls.querySelector('.slider .progress');
var player = audioPlayer.querySelector('audio');
var currentTime = audioPlayer.querySelector('.current-time');
var totalTime = audioPlayer.querySelector('.total-time');
var speaker = audioPlayer.querySelector('#speaker');

var draggableClasses = ['pin'];
var currentlyDragged = null;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {

  if(!isDraggable(event.target)) return false;

  currentlyDragged = event.target;
  let handleMethod = currentlyDragged.dataset.method;

  this.addEventListener('mousemove', window[handleMethod], false);

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    currentlyDragged = false;
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', window[handleMethod], false);
  }, false);  
});

playpauseBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
player.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);
player.addEventListener('volumechange', updateVolume);
player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
  totalTime.textContent = formatTime(player.duration);
});
player.addEventListener('canplay', makePlay);
player.addEventListener('ended', function(){
  playPause.attributes.d.value = "M18 12L0 24V0";
  player.currentTime = 0;
});

volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  volumeBtn.classList.toggle('open');
  volumeControls.classList.toggle('hidden');
})

window.addEventListener('resize', directionAware);

sliders.forEach(slider => {
  let pin = slider.querySelector('.pin');
  slider.addEventListener('click', window[pin.dataset.method]);
});

directionAware();

function isDraggable(el) {
  let canDrag = false;
  let classes = Array.from(el.classList);
  draggableClasses.forEach(draggable => {
    if(classes.indexOf(draggable) !== -1)
      canDrag = true;
  })
  return canDrag;
}

function inRange(event) {
  let rangeBox = getRangeBox(event);
  let rect = rangeBox.getBoundingClientRect();
  let direction = rangeBox.dataset.direction;
  if(direction == 'horizontal') {
    var min = rangeBox.offsetLeft;
    var max = min + rangeBox.offsetWidth;   
    if(event.clientX < min || event.clientX > max) return false;
  } else {
    var min = rect.top;
    var max = min + rangeBox.offsetHeight; 
    if(event.clientY < min || event.clientY > max) return false;  
  }
  return true;
}

function updateProgress() {
  var current = player.currentTime;
  var percent = (current / player.duration) * 100;
  progress.style.width = percent + '%';

  currentTime.textContent = formatTime(current);
}

function updateVolume() {
  volumeProgress.style.height = player.volume * 100 + '%';
  if(player.volume >= 0.5) {
    speaker.attributes.d.value = 'M14.667 0v2.747c3.853 1.146 6.666 4.72 6.666 8.946 0 4.227-2.813 7.787-6.666 8.934v2.76C20 22.173 24 17.4 24 11.693 24 5.987 20 1.213 14.667 0zM18 11.693c0-2.36-1.333-4.386-3.333-5.373v10.707c2-.947 3.333-2.987 3.333-5.334zm-18-4v8h5.333L12 22.36V1.027L5.333 7.693H0z';  
  } else if(player.volume < 0.5 && player.volume > 0.05) {
    speaker.attributes.d.value = 'M0 7.667v8h5.333L12 22.333V1L5.333 7.667M17.333 11.373C17.333 9.013 16 6.987 14 6v10.707c2-.947 3.333-2.987 3.333-5.334z';
  } else if(player.volume <= 0.05) {
    speaker.attributes.d.value = 'M0 7.667v8h5.333L12 22.333V1L5.333 7.667';
  }
}

function getRangeBox(event) {
  let rangeBox = event.target;
  let el = currentlyDragged;
  if(event.type == 'click' && isDraggable(event.target)) {
    rangeBox = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  }
  if(event.type == 'mousemove') {
    rangeBox = el.parentElement.parentElement;
  }
  return rangeBox;
}

function getCoefficient(event) {
  let slider = getRangeBox(event);
  let rect = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
  let K = 0;
  if(slider.dataset.direction == 'horizontal') {

    let offsetX = event.clientX - slider.offsetLeft;
    let width = slider.clientWidth;
    K = offsetX / width;    

  } else if(slider.dataset.direction == 'vertical') {

    let height = slider.clientHeight;
    var offsetY = event.clientY - rect.top;
    K = 1 - offsetY / height;

  }
  return K;
}

function rewind(event) {
  if(inRange(event)) {
    player.currentTime = player.duration * getCoefficient(event);
  }
}

function changeVolume(event) {
  if(inRange(event)) {
    player.volume = getCoefficient(event);
  }
}

function formatTime(time) {
  var min = Math.floor(time / 60);
  var sec = Math.floor(time % 60);
  return min + ':' + ((sec<10) ? ('0' + sec) : sec);
}

function togglePlay() {
  if(player.paused) {
    playPause.attributes.d.value = "M0 0h6v24H0zM12 0h6v24h-6z";
    player.play();
  } else {
    playPause.attributes.d.value = "M18 12L0 24V0";
    player.pause();
  }  
}

function makePlay() {
  playpauseBtn.style.display = 'block';
  loading.style.display = 'none';
}

function directionAware() {
  if(window.innerHeight < 250) {
    volumeControls.style.bottom = '-54px';
    volumeControls.style.left = '54px';
  } else if(audioPlayer.offsetTop < 154) {
    volumeControls.style.bottom = '-164px';
    volumeControls.style.left = '-3px';
  } else {
    volumeControls.style.bottom = '52px';
    volumeControls.style.left = '-3px';
  }
}
```

[I also believe it may be just a syntax problem ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDl2v.png)

Comment: Are you sure the animation name `spin` is not defined anywhere else on your page? Does your wordpress theme have it? It seems like a very common animation name, try changing the name to `spinonce` or something else. If that fails, don't set the animation repeat to infinite; just set it to `animation: spin 0.4s linear 1`.

Comment: thank you @jasmonate but it seems like it's not the issue...

I think it is a syntax problem... but I don't know why it wouldn't work on my website and it works on codepen !

Comment: @Paulie_D I corrected that sorry !